# Get column names postgres

Tags: c++, postgresql

I am new to POSTGRES.I want to make a SELECT and list all the columns names and values.

Is there a function in library libpq-fe.h to get the column names of a sql query ?

Comment: Have a look at function `PQsetResultAttrs(PGresult *res, int numAttributes, PGresAttDesc *attDescs)` - it may be what you're after, but I haven't used postgres from C myself, so not too sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Delphi code I use LibPQ and `PQfname(SelectHandle, ColumnNr);` . It is described in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-exec.html